# Hive Difference between 2 records

Tags: hive, lag, records, difference

I have records with date and state. I want to display only the records which states have changed from the previous record.

Example input

```
date                  state
2013-01-15 04:15:07.602 ON
2013-01-15 05:15:08.502 ON
2013-01-15 06:15:08.502 OFF
2013-01-15 07:15:08.502 ON
2013-01-15 08:15:08.502 ON
...
```

Output expected

```
date                    state
2013-01-15 04:15:07.602 ON
2013-01-15 06:15:08.502 OFF
2013-01-15 07:15:08.502 ON
```

I wrote a simple `udf` function (tmchange in my query) which returns the value if state has changed and null otherwise.

```
select t.date, t.state from (SELECT date,  state, tmchange(LAG(state, 1) 
over (PARTITION BY month(date) ORDER BY date), state ) as lagres  
from demo_table where state is not null  
and  year=2013) t where t.lagres is not null ;
```

I use the `LAG` function from hive windowing functions. The problem is I get  `error: Java heap space` when I use `PARTITION by month(date)` . When I try `PARTITION by weekofyear(date)` it works but it takes really too much time probably due to the `LAG` function.
Do you have any idea how I can optimize my query in order to meet this needs (more generally compare a record to a previous one). Is it really the `LAG` function to use in this case ?

Comment: How much memory do the mappers and reducers have?

Comment: @Krishna you change the title of my post from "Hive" to "Have". Could you please move back to "Apache Hive" which is what I meant.

Comment: Map: 682MB  Reduce: 2048MB  "Map-side sot buffer memory": 273MB

Comment: @baptiste i am dealing with similar kind of issue. my input data is similar to yours and my expected is similar to the one you mentioned above. Can you please post the UDF script here so i can try it out.                                 Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Not sure you can make it go any faster unless you reduce the partition size. Can you just partition by the date instead of month or week: `PARTITION BY month(date), day(date)`

Why use a UDF? Wouldn't this work:

```
SELECT t.date, t.state 
FROM (
  SELECT
    date, 
    state, 
    LAG(state) OVER (PARTITION BY month(date) ORDER BY date) AS prev_state
  FROM demo_table 
  WHERE state IS NOT NULL and year=2013
) t 
WHERE t.prev_state != t.state ;
```